# google voice search latency and time calculations

Tags: speech-recognition

I know that Google Voice Search works by sending the raw audio (digitized of course) to Google's servers, then Google returns a result in a textual form.

The result itself is relatively small (unless it's a very long sentence...), so I believe the time it takes to send it over the Internet is negligible (discounting HTTP overhead, server load, etc.).

What I'm interested to know is the size (KB) of the actual "analog" raw audio sent to Google's speech servers, in order to get a ballpark figure of this component's dependency on Internet connection speed (uplink).

Of course, the size of that raw audio packet is very dependent on the phrase spoken (one word? entire sentence? a very long sentence?), so I am looking for some statistical information about this (average, typical, etc.).

I also know that those raw audio packets are compressed. Any information on the compression method? (it's not MP3, or is it?)

Is the compression different between Android devices and PCs (i.e. Chrome based)?

While this may seem not a direct programming question, in my case it is very directly related to programming because the answer may affect the algorithm(s) to be used when building an application based on Google Voice Search.

Comment: Take a look at http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/. This post shows the workings of Google Chrome's speech recognition. The assumption most people have made is that Android uses the same services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't measured how much data is actually sent to the Google servers, but lets make a reasonable assumption that Voice Search

- records mono
- records with 16kHz sample rate
- records with 16-bit resolution
- applies lossless compression achieving 2x smaller size

In this case 1 second of recording consumes `(1 * 16,000 * 2) / 2 = 16,000 bytes`.